# Java applications getting squeezed via remote desktop with 16bit color depth

Tags: java, remote-desktop, rdesktop

I am managing some virtual desktops running Windows 7 Enterprise SP1 x64. When running any Java applications (tested on 7u13, 7u21 and 7u25) the windows are getting squeezed to the left.

[image: squeezed java windows]

The black area is the whole window. I am able to e.g. click the buttons when I hit the correct position in the black area.

This happens when using rdesktop 1.7.1, FreeRDP 1.0.1 and the client which is used by our Linux based thin clients (unsure which exactly, but I guess rdesktop, too). The native Windows 7 mstsc.exe does <s>not show this behaviour.</s> show this behaviour, too. The problem arises when the connection uses 16 bit color depth.

Unfortunately our (pretty old) thin clients work not so well when using 32bit color.

Any Ideas what causes this behaviour and how to solve it?

Comment: Updated question. Problem is 16bit color depth.

Comment: Use 24 bit color depth? I've never had good results with either 32-bit or 16-bit color depth.

Comment: Is there a possibility to use 24 bit with Win7? Only found solutions to enable 24 bit for XP/2003.

Comment: this https://askubuntu.com/questions/406815/remote-desktop-connection-color-not-proper showed me how to fix a similar problem I had